# Is it possible to ensure JSON key order considering Maps?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have the creation a JSON with a certain order in his keys given the following scenario:

```
const one = {"a": 123, "b": 345, "c": 567};
const two = {"b": 123, "a": 345, "c": 567};
const three = {"c": 123, "a": 345, "b": 567};
```

Then I run the following examples:

```
let result = {};
[one, two, three].forEach(thing => {
const keys = Object.keys(thing);
keys.forEach(key => {
    result[key] = thing[key];
  });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

will produce this output:

```
{
  "a": 345,
  "b": 567,
  "c": 123
}
```

If I run the following one:

```
result = {};
[three, one, two].forEach(thing => {
    const keys = Object.keys(thing);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        result[key] = thing[key];
    });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

I would get this other one:

```
{
  "c": 567,
  "a": 345,
  "b": 123
}
```

Saying this the initial values of the JSON would eventually define the order of the JSON keys.
But then getting deeper on it I see that the specification of any JSON  [is unorder by nature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html)
And then in order to comply with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) that says that Maps conserve the order of the keys considering the insertion order.
And so I did the following one:

```
const templateMap = new Map();
templateMap.set('a', '');
templateMap.set('b', '');
templateMap.set('c', '');
```

Therefor I know now that for sure the initial insertion order will be conserved...

```
const objectWithKeysInOrder = Object.fromEntries(templateMap);
[three, one, two].forEach(thing => {
    const keys = Object.keys(thing);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        objectWithKeysInOrder[key] = thing[key];
    });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(objectWithKeysInOrder, null, 2));
```

Then the results again are:

```
{
  "a": 345,
  "b": 123,
  "c": 567
}
```

But then the question is, given the fact that I ensure the insertion order with a map, and created an object from the entries of the map.

Am I safe to say that the object will be read by any reader even getting this JSON through the network with the keys in order?
Will they have the same JSON.stringify with those keys in the same order I see?

Thanks in advance for the time and knowledge sharing

Comment: My opinion is your code is too fragile if it depends on the order of an inherently unordered data structure to be retained. In other words: why does this matter for your project?

Comment: Agreed, but still suppose you get a JSON from the network is it always in the same order those keys? just to put another point of view of the question.

Comment: The network does not change the order but any parser of the data on the other end may change it.

Comment: @juangarcia: The *JSON* will always be in the same order as long as it's the same JSON, because JSON is just a string.  Nothing would have any reason to re-order parts of a string.  But once that JSON is deserialized into an object, the order of properties in that object shouldn't be relied upon.  It's not really clear what issue led to this question or what, if any, problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What @luk2302 said – you don't "get a JSON from the network", you get a bunch of bytes and then you interpret (parse) them as JSON. You could write a JSON parser that doesn't output JavaScript objects at all, but just a flat list of key-value pairs.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON - aka the text based serialization of JavaScript objects

Comment: Just as a mention, the map isn't needed at all - objects store non-symbol non-array-index properties in creation order as well, so you could just start with `result = { a: undefined, b: undefined, c: undefined };`. The relevant issue is, whether that order will be kept, when serializing and deserializing to/from JSON.

Comment: yes the map was just part of my uncertainty and research, but at the end is as you mention @ASDFGerte the order of things when serializing and deserealizing to/from JSON through any network... I could not answer my self, and I wouldnot know where to look for this either

Comment: may be there is none, and as mentioned @David this is just an string that travels and as you see it will be sent and then will be parsed in the order of the serialized keys.

Comment: As others already mentioned, whether there is any network involved also doesn't matter. The only question is, whether a simple `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` is by spec allowed to mangle the order.

Comment: I can safely state that JSON.stringify will conserve the order of the keys due to the last bullet of the description in MDN, that clarifies, that it uses Object.keys which works in order across platforms. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description 
JSON parse not sure yet (in my case is used behind the scenes in nestjs + express parser)

Comment: From that same bullet on MDN: "For example, `JSON.stringify` on the same object will always produce the same string, and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` would produce an object with the same key ordering as the original (assuming the object is completely JSON-serializable)."

Comment: The usual key-order caveats would still apply, such as number-like keys being reordered.

Comment: Your last statement is very enlightning I would say. For instance if we do JSON.stringify({1: "asdf", 2: "wert", 10: "wqerq", 5:"qqwq"}) this would produce this value '{"1":"asdf","2":"wert","5":"qqwq","10":"wqerq"}' which is completely unexpected for me, even if the keys where string... I will enrich my answer below with your findings, thx

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone who hits this situation, and tries to work with ordered keys generated by a map or other ordered structure to generate a JSON with keys in order.
This is a no way to go, don't trust in trying to make an ordered solution out of an unordered JSON by writing on such structure in order or verifying JSON stringify the results of it.

JSON stringify in particular will work with Object.keys which is in order and generate the serialization of those values accordingly. But the JSON parse there is no comments on being in order, further more some development is shown in npm in order to make a [json parser in order](https://github.com/sanderevers/json-in-order).
Here is the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html) that defines it as unordered.

Is a weak statement trying to force this unordered structure to be ordered, better go with an array or working with maps without passing through it when order is needed.

One example of unexpected values in disorder would be with keys of type number or string that could be parsed as number:

```
JSON.stringify({1: "asdf", 2: "wert", 10: "wqerq", 5:"qqwq"})
```

would produce this values

```
'{"1":"asdf","2":"wert","5":"qqwq","10":"wqerq"}'
```

and this:

```
JSON.stringify({"1": "asdf", "2": "wert", "10": "wqerq", "5":"qqwq"})
```

woudl produce this results too

```
'{"1":"asdf","2":"wert","5":"qqwq","10":"wqerq"}'
```

making the parse of this values to out of order too when I do the parse. Saying this we have a clear example unexpected key values to be defined out of order after stringify and parse due to the nature of unorder jsons as defined also in the page [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)